# CSS and JS Not Found in Servlet with Annotation

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp, servlets

I'm creating basic web application using Servlet and JSP. There is no web.xml as I'm using annotation-based servlets. Here is the structure:

```
basic-servlet-and-jsp
- src
  - main
    - java
    - resources
    - webapp
      - _includes
      - assets
      - about.jsp
      - home.jsp
- pom.xml
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.github.julianjupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic-servlet-and-jsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Basic Servlet and JSP</name>
    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <finalName>basic-servlet-and-jsp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is my code for the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

which is generated as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/basic-servlet-and-jsp/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

And for the JavaScript:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/vendor/popper/dist/umd//popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="/basic-servlet-and-jsp/assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/basic-servlet-and-jsp/assets/vendor/popper/dist/umd//popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/basic-servlet-and-jsp/assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm sure they are all existing in their respective paths. Googling gives me similar way of including CSS and JS. But, these links are not found whenever I run them.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How are you creating your war file?

Comment: While I am sure that you can get this to work. I would suggest that for common javascript dependencies such as the ones you linked here you would receive better performance by linking to a CDN providing them, or lacking that an S3 bucket.  This sort of side steps the issue but if you do not have any custom scripts of your own it is definitely the easiest and fastest.  If you were taking an app to prod that is how you would normally want to manage these sorts of dependencies.

Comment: So far I haven't created/exported war file. I'm just running it via Eclipse.

Comment: I can't use CDN for they are blocked in our network. I really have to use local resources (CSS, JS).

Answer (score 0):

I just add in the web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.app.Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I do this in Java (annotation, or anything)? Like I said, I don't use web.xml.